# Firebase Realtime. Fields filled in different fields

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When registering the data are going to fields other than firebase realtime I am not understanding why this problem, could someone help me?

the problem is that when filling
address field in the firebase record it fills with email and the email fills with phone number. does anyone know what i'm doing wrong?

---

Users.java

```
public class User {
    public String helpsms;
    public String email;
    public String phone;
    public String address;
    public String fullname ;



    public User(String helpsms, String address, String email, String phone, String fullname) {
        this.helpsms = helpsms;
        this.email = email;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.address = address;
        this.fullname = fullname;
    }
}
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your constructor is wrong. I would prefer you generate by itself.

As you see here, your parameter already set address as 2nd parameter.

```
 public User(String helpsms, String address, String email, String phone, String fullname) {
        this.helpsms = helpsms;
        this.email = email;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.address = address;
        this.fullname = fullname;
    }
```

So I would suggest you to delete them all.
And if you are using Windows, click anywhere in the class and then press ALT + INSERT. Choose the constructor and select all.

or you can do manually as here.

```
 public User(String helpsms, String email, String phone, String address, String fullname) {
        this.helpsms = helpsms;
        this.email = email;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.address = address;
        this.fullname = fullname;
    }
```